# Excel Macro: Import specific CSV-file instead of selecting it

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I use the following Macro to import a CSV-file into Excel.
The Macro itself works fine, but when I start the Macro, I always have to select which CSV-file I want to import (a file selection dialog appears).

Is there a way to automatically select `C:\test\testfile.csv` instead of the file selection dialog?

Thank you!

```
Sub GetCSVList()
    Dim dlgOpen As FileDialog
    Set dlgOpen = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets("Tickets").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    With dlgOpen
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        ''Start in
        .InitialFileName = "C:\test"
        .Show
    End With

    For Each fname In dlgOpen.SelectedItems
        ImportCSV fname
    Next
End Sub


Sub ImportCSV(fname)
    Set ws = Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
    ws.Name = "Tickets"

    With ws.QueryTables.Add( _
            Connection:="TEXT;" & fname, _
            Destination:=Range("A1"))
        .Name = "Test" & Worksheets.Count + 1
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 65001
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        '.UseListObject = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of the following where you don't open the dialog picker and instead open by using the filepath?

```
  Sub GetCSVList()
    ' Dim dlgOpen As FileDialog
    ' Set dlgOpen = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    Dim filepath As String
    filepath = "C:\test\testfile.csv"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets("Tickets").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ' With dlgOpen
    '    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    '   ''Start in
    '  .InitialFileName = "C:\test"
    ' .Show
    'End With

    'For Each fname In dlgOpen.SelectedItems
    ImportCSV filepath
'Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

change your GetCSVList sub ....

```
Sub GetCSVList()

  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  On Error Resume Next
  Worksheets("Tickets").Delete
  On Error GoTo 0
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True

  ImportCSV "C:\test\testfile.csv"

End Sub
```

Comment: Generally, this works fine - but I have a lot of cell references to the worksheet "Ticket" and they don't work anymore when I delete the whole workbook and import it afterwards. I tried "  Worksheets("Tickets").Range("A1:Z9999").Clear" instead of your code, but then I get the error that the worksheet already exists. Is there a way to do this without loosing the references?

Comment: you did not say anything about that in your question. please post another question for that issue.